# Why nuxt-i18n module doesn't seem to be loaded? ( _vm.$t is not a function)

Tags: javascript, internationalization, nuxt.js

So I came to work on my project today and I got greated by this error with nuxt.js.

I removed node_modules and .nuxt folder, reissue a `yarn install` but I still have this error, `_vm.$t is not a function`.

Where does it come from?

I also got some `_vm.localePath is not a function`...

I made sure it was in my modules too:

```
modules: [
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      locales: [
        { code: 'en', iso: 'en-US', name:'English', file: 'en-US.json' },
        { code: 'fr', iso: 'fr-FR', name:'Français', file: 'fr.js' },
        // { code: 'es', iso: 'es-ES', name:'English', file: 'es.js' }
      ],
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      // strategy: 'prefix_and_default',
      lazy: true,
      langDir: 'i18n/',
      // By default, custom routes are extracted from page files using acorn parsing,
      // set this to false to disable this
      parsePages: true,

    }],
...
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My classy Nuxt.js project",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.0.0",
    "fastify": "^1.11.0",
    "iview": "^3.0.1",
    "koa": "^2.3.0",
    "nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "nuxt-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^5.2.1",
    "pg": "^7.4.3",
    "vuetify": "^1.0.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Koa and Vuetify will be replaced by fastify and iview, that is why they are there.

As spotted in the comments, nuxt is version 1.0.0 for a strange reason. I upgraded the package to nuxt 1.4.2. I still have the same issue.

Complete stack trace:

```
Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
[Vue warn]: Property or method "localePath" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Default> at layouts/default.vue
       <Root>
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.localePath is not a function"

found in

---> <Default> at layouts/default.vue
       <Root>
{ TypeError: _vm.localePath is not a function
    at Proxy.render (layouts/default.vue?2d02:32:0)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:4542:22)
    at renderComponentInner (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7532:25)
    at renderComponent (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7502:5)
    at RenderContext.renderNode (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7418:5)
    at RenderContext.next (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2436:14)
    at cachedWrite (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2295:9)
    at renderElement (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7656:5)
    at renderNode (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7420:5)
    at renderComponentInner (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7538:3)
    at renderComponent (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7502:5)
    at RenderContext.renderNode (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7418:5)
    at RenderContext.next (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2436:14)
    at RenderContext.next (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2449:12)
    at cachedWrite (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2295:9)
    at renderElement (/media/drive/srv/node/ooo/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7646:5) statusCode: 500, name: 'TypeError' }
```

Comment: Show your packages file

Comment: Oops, of course, edited.

Comment: @Aldarund do you see an issue? :\ (I forgot to tag you earlier)

Comment: Nuxt version that installed is 1.0.0 or 1.4.1 ?

Comment: @Aldarund, it's suppose to be 1.4.1 as I cloned from https://github.com/nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app but indeed this file says 1.0.0. I'll try upgrading this.

Comment: I just ended up spending an hour recreating the project and transferring everything over. It works...

Comment: @HypeWolf I have the same error , how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Edit]** I don't know if the question was edited after I added the answer or I just didn't understand the question correctly, but my answer describes how to resolve the error in testing environment.

If you have this issue out of testing environment - this answer will not help you, sorry.

---

Late for the party, but just had to resolve the same issue, so I'll leave it here just in case.

[One way to resolve the problem as mentioned here](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/323) is:

```js
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
  mocks: {
    // Always returns the input
    $t: i => i,
    localePath: i => i
  }
});
```

---

However, I've recently found a better way:

`./tests/jest.setup.js`:

```js
// https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4115
import Vue from 'vue'
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'

Vue.config.silent = true

// Mock Nuxt components
config.stubs['nuxt-link'] = true; // string stabs like '<a><slot /></a>' are now depreciated
config.stubs['no-ssr'] = true;
config.mocks.$t = i => i;
config.mocks.localePath = i => i;
```

`./jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/tests/jest.setup.js'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest'
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue'
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    'cypress',
  ],
}
```

Surprisingly enough, I don't need to install [ts-jest package](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) at least now even though I use [Nuxt Typescript](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/).

Then in each test suite I need to use the mock I've already mentioned on top of this answer.

Comment: How does this answer resolve the issue? I actually have the same problem as in the question itself and there is nothing mentioned about a test.
Is there any solution yet when I DONT want to mock the $t method?